# Can't connect to the SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, linux, ubuntu

Good morning.  I use Ubuntu 16.04 64-bit on an Asus ROG G50V, 4Gb laptop. I'm trying to learn SQL, but I've been having nothing but trouble and headaches getting it to work.

So, thus far, I've installed SQL Server according to Microsoft's "sql-server-linux-setup" instructions, and then I've tried to connect to the server following (again) Microsoft's "linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu" these instructions, and so [I keep getting results like this: (there's supposed to be a screenshot image here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTme9.jpg)
The system has consistently told me that my password is wrong, so I've tried to fix it following these instructions:
http://techgenix.com/reset-mysql-root-password-forgotten/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried entering your password without the ' and <>

Comment: Indeed. I've tried all the various possibilities of it, quotes but no angles, angles but no quotes, quotes and angles, neither, no password at all, nothing has worked.

Comment: just out of curious, do you have a login named 'kourosh' in your sql server instance?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.